# Does anyone know the physical dimensions of the Microchip PICkit4 programmer?

Tags: programmer, pickit, dimensions

Does anyone know the physical dimensions of the Microchip PICkit4 programmer ([PG164140](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/PG164140))?  It would be useful to know so that I can leave proper clearance on my PCB around the programming header.

I already looked in the following documents but I couldn't find any dimensions listed.

- [MPLAB® PICkit™ 4 In-Circuit Debugger User's Guide](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002751F.pdf)
- [MPLAB® PICkitTM 4 In-Circuit Debugger QUICK START GUIDE](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002721B.pdf)

The dimensions I need are labeled A, B, C in the following diagram.
[image]

Please note that I will accept an answer based on measurements of an actual unit taken with calipers if someone wants to do this.  But an actual drawing provided by Microchip Corporation would be better.

Comment: Why do you need clearance on your board for the main body of the device? It connects to the programing header via a cable. You just need room for the programming header.

Comment: @TypeIA I normally use mine connected directly to the board's (usually R/A) header pins. I've had a handful of failures using a cable, so I prefer to avoid if possible. And I've had the same clearance issue as noted by OP, which I've usually got around by using a short extension header when needed.

Comment: @TypeIA the I own a PICKit3 and I don't believe it came with any kind of ribbon cable.  While purchasing and using a ribbon cable is possible, I usually plugged it directly into the PCB.  The images of the PICKit4 on Microchip's website don't seem to show that it comes with a cable other than for USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a ruler on my unit, I measure (to the nearest millimetre):

A=85mm

B=43mm

C=13mm

The connector itself is just under 21mm wide (standard 2.54mm x 8p).